# Show ContentDialog in PrintDetailedOptionsOptionChanged in UWP

Tags: printing, uwp

I am trying to show a content dialog while PrintManager is being shown. I tried the following code, but the window is shown behind PrintManager and is only accessible after PrintManager is closed.

Here is the Code:

```
Await printDocument.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, Async Sub()
                                                                                                 If dlgPrint Is Nothing Then dlgPrint = New dlgPrint
                                                                                                 dlgPrint.value = sender.Options("CustomSize").Value
                                                                                                 dlgPrint.pictures = NumberOfPhotos
                                                                                                 Dim a As IAsyncOperation(Of ContentDialogResult) = dlgPrint.ShowAsync
                                                                                                 dlgPrint.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic)
                                                                                                 Dim res As ContentDialogResult = Await (a)
                                                                                                 If res = ContentDialogResult.Secondary Then
                                                                                                   sender.Options("CustomSize").TrySetValue(dlgPrint.value)
                                                                                                 End If
                                                                                               End Sub)
```

Comment: It seems like by design.  Even your main UI cannot be accessed if you don't close the print UI, moreover the `ContentDialog`. The main thread seems like waiting for the print thread until it ended.

Comment: Thats what I feared...

Comment: So why you need this feature?

Comment: I want to enter picture width and height for printing in inches or centimeters.

Comment: I know that it would be possible to add two textboxes, but I want to have a mask for input and the possibility to select inches or centimeters.